# Given a matrix nxd, what is the radius of its hypersphere?

Tags: geometry, spheres, spherical-geometry

Given the matrix:

[image]

[image]

Centered on μ=0

What would be the radius of its hypersphere?

Comment: You say hypercube in the title and hypersphere in the text...

Comment: Besides, if you mean the circumscribed sphere, you must have  $n=d+1$ [only one point more than the dimension (e.g., 3 points for a circle in dimension 2)]

Comment: @JeanMarie, apologies I have corrected the title, I have been trying to learn about both. Assuming n=d+1, how would you calculate the radius?

Comment: See the answer of Achille Hui [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2413725). You will also find formulas for the volume, surface, etc. with the keyword "hypersphere"